# Cannot load projects in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, sdk

I upgraded my Visual Studio version (I don't remember exactly but it was 17.4 or something) to 17.7.4. After upgrading VS, the XAML Hotload does not work any more even though I already have it enabled in the settings. So what I did was I uninstalled VS and installed previous version 17.4.0. After that, whenever I opened VS, I see this error message:

[image]

Then, when I close this error popup, I got this error:

[image]

The next issue appeared is the project cannot be loaded. I right-click on the project and load it, but it doesn't work. Got this error instead:

[image]

Also, I see this error in the output console:
[image]

I tried all the solutions I could found but nothing worked. I also cannot open other project using C++ as well. Creating new project gives the same error. I also uninstalled and re-installed the new version 17.7.4 but the errors don't go away. What might be wrong with VS?